# Why a string that has some value is returning true when checking if it contains ""?

Tags: string, vb.net, contains, uipath

A **scenario** where the variable tempMID of type string containing value "338715618884", checks if it contains "" or not. It is returning true. Why is this happening? in my understanding, this shouldn't return true.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0#system-string-contains(system-string)):

> `String.Contains` returns `true` if the value parameter occurs within
> this string, **or if value is the empty string ("")**; otherwise, `false`.

So it's working as expected. The language designer have decided that an empty string is contained in every existing string, which makes sense to me.

Comment: how to deal with it?

Comment: @AnujMasand: What is the problem?

Comment: Sir, I am getting an empty value in a generic variable which then I am comparing with tempMID and expecting false as the string I am checking for is empty.

Comment: @AnujMasand: Check if the value is `String.Empty` before you use `Contains`, then you can split the logic and do the `false`-branch if it's empty.

Comment: @AnujMasand If the empty string is actually in a variable, e.g. `checkFor = ""`, then you could check that first: `If checkFor = "" Then Return False` and then do your Contains code.

Comment: When thinking in Regex, you get used to think of string "HELLO" like this "" + "H" + "" +"E" + ""+"L" +""+ "L"+"" +"O"